# Can't run service in Angular2 test (code copy pasted from the docs)

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following error **(unit testing Angular2)**:

> Cannot configure the test module when the test module has already been
>   instantiated. Make sure you are not using `inject` before
>   `TestBed.configureTestingModule`

Here is my code (it's basically a copy paste from the angular docs) which throws the above error:

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component'
import { MyServiceService } from './my-service.service'

beforeEach(() => {
  // stub UserService for test purposes
  let userServiceStub = {
    isLoggedIn: true,
    user: { name: 'Test User'}
  };

  TestBed.configureTestingModule({

     declarations: [ AppComponent],
     providers:    [ {provide: MyServiceService, useValue: userServiceStub } ]
  });

  let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
  let comp    = fixture.componentInstance;
  // UserService from the root injector
  let userService = TestBed.get(MyServiceService);
  //  get the "welcome" element by CSS selector (e.g., by class name)
  let de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.nesto'));
  let el = de.nativeElement;

  it('should welcome "Bubba"', () => {
    userService.user.name = 'something'; // welcome message hasn't been shown yet
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(el.textContent).toContain('some');
  });
});
```

I want to run a service but it seems that I just can't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely problem is that you're attempting to run testing within your `beforeEach()`. You need to make sure all `it()` methods are outside/after the `beforeEach()`:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  // stub UserService for test purposes
  let userServiceStub = {
    isLoggedIn: true,
    user: { name: 'Test User'}
  };

  TestBed.configureTestingModule({

     declarations: [ AppComponent],
     providers:    [ {provide: MyServiceService, useValue: userServiceStub } ]
  });

  let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
  let comp    = fixture.componentInstance;

  // get the "welcome" element by CSS selector (e.g., by class name)
  let de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.nesto'));
  let el = de.nativeElement;
});


it('should welcome "Bubba"', inject([MyServiceService], (userService) => {
  userService.user.name = 'something'; // welcome message hasn't been shown yet
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(el.textContent).toContain('some');
}));
```

Comment: It sill complains... Also userService.user.name is not accessible because the variable is declared in the beforeEach scope...

Comment: Glossed over that part. You need to `inject()` the service into your `it()` in order to access it inside. Updated answer.

Comment: Assumed the service was 'UserService', and not 'MyServiceService'. That data will be available since you listed it as a provider as long as you inject the service into your `it()` properly. The `inject()` is the equivalent of `TestBed.get()`

Comment: It says:" can not find name inject", Also the inject practice can not be found on the angular test official page.

Comment: I imported the inject and the most important part was to REMOVE the let **userService = TestBed.get(MyServiceService);** line of code  and now it works. Could you provide the working example with the TestBed so that I remove the inject part?

Comment: If you don't want to inject the service you'd have to include the `userService.user.name = 'something';` `fixture.detectChanges();` inside the `beforeEach()`. Injecting services for testing is standard, and can be found here: https://angular.io/guide/testing#the-inject-function

Answer (score 0):

This works, removed the instance in the beforeEach() and injected into the it().

All credits go to Z. Bagley

```
import { TestBed, async, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component'
import { MyServiceService } from './my-service.service'
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';

beforeEach(() => {
  // stub UserService for test purposes
  let userServiceStub = {
    isLoggedIn: true,
    user: { name: 'Test User'}
  };

  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
     declarations: [ AppComponent],
     providers:    [ {provide: MyServiceService, useValue: userServiceStub } ]
  });
});
  it('should welcome "Bubba"', inject([MyServiceService], (userService) => {
    let fixture=TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(userService.user.name).toContain('se');
}));
```